# connecting phantomjs as selenium driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I installed phantomjs 1.6 using

## sudo apt-get install phantomjs

Got the following error when I tried creating a selenium webdriver using phantomjs in python.

### "WebDriverException: Message: 'Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.' ; Screenshot: available via screen"

Did the same as suggested in [here](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/236), except that I kept the port as an argument after using the default suggested one with no luck. However, now in both cases I get a different error

### "WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to GhostDriver'"

Some idea behind both the errors which does make sense - [here](http://derekkwok.net/p/4/failing-tests-with-selenium-phantomjs-and-pycharm/).

Any idea as to how to make it work?

Comment: what does python have to do with the question?

Comment: one of the failure points could have been the python selenium binding as suggested in one of the links mentioned above. And yeah, totally irrelevant after finding out the workaround and I will remove the tag gladly.

Comment: The workaround -> sudo npm install -g phantomjs